# MySQL: Mass Conversion Script for Table Engine

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I'm trying to figure out how to convert en mass from database table engine A to table engine B (in this case, from MyISAM to InnoDB).  I know I can do it for individual tables using the MySQL workbench, but i'd like a script or a program that can do the conversion en mass.  Anyone got any ideas?

*** EDIT *** I'd prefer an SQL query that I could use to do this, without using php, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pseudo code using [information_schema tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html):

```
$rows = "SELECT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourDBName'
        AND ENGINE LIKE 'engineA'";
foreach ($rows as $table) {
    $query = 'ALTER TABLE '.$table.' ENGINE = engineB';
}
```

Comment: got something that is in an SQL script, or some other scripting language other than php?

Comment: @EvilPhoenix: That's not even really PHP.  It's pseudo-code.  Implement it in your language of choice...  It shouldn't be too difficult...

Comment: Got it.  Implemented this with a bash script.  Thanks for the help.